# What is $f'(0)$ for $f(x) = x^{1/3} \sin x$? Does the product rule give a different answer?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)= x^{1/3} \sin x$. Say we want to find the derivative using the rules of differentiation.

So $f'(x)=\sin(x) x^{-2/3} + \cos(x) x^{1/3}$, and we see that
$f'(0)$ is undefined.

But if we use the deriavtive defenition we seem to get zero. How can these be different?

Comment: Your computation of $f'$ via the product rule is wrong: since $x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at zero, the product rule does not apply.

Comment: So yo meant here that the derivative rules failed here and we have to use the defenition

Comment: But if you take f(x)=x^1/3 and  if you find the derivative using both  rules and defeinition the answer will be undefined

Comment: so what is the method to know that the derivative will fail while using rules and success using defenition,, in my opinion I think if the rules  get to you undefined check the definition  if  you get undefined too so it's undefined

Comment: I'd just take the limit of $f'$

Comment: @N74: taking limit of derivative $f'$ may not help always, but in the current question it is ok.

Comment: "Just take the limit" is not valid in all cases and is not good mathematical advice.

Answer (score 1):

The product rule states that for two **differentiable** functions $f,g$, we have that
$\frac{d}{dx}fg(x) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$. But in your example, $x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $0$, and so you cannot use the product rule to determine differentiability of $x^{1/3} \sin x$ at $x = 0$.

As you note in your post, using the definition of the derivative directly shows that $x^{1/3} \sin x$ is differentiable at $0$, and the derivative has value $0$ at $0$.

Comment: Okey what about f(x)= x^(1/3) *1  and if you use both defenition and and rules you will get the same undefined ,so how you can know if rules will fail or  it's same  as the the def

Comment: @MarkWilYuan No, you still can't use the product rule there since it's still true that $x^{1/3}$ isn't differentiable. This is the exact same obstruction as in your case.